# It is possible to run a dataflow DLP de-idenification job on a group of files in GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dlp

I have a large amount of csv files in a folder that I need to run a de-identification job on and was wondering if anyone knew of any way that I could run that job on the folder/multiple files?
At the moment I'm creating dataflow jobs with DLP templates and that's worked fine for single datasets.
I know in GCS you can run DLPs on folders with multiple files in it but there you're only allowed to use inspection templates and not de-identification templates.

Putting them into a bucket is also not a option as the parent folder is already a bucket and buckets can't be nested.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: Because you can't run a DLP job with deidentification, I assume that you can't. Only the content API can be called with a deidentication template, but you need to send it the bytestrinf to deidentify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, this feature is not yet supported. The recommended solution is to use dataflow.

Comment: In dataflow would it not be possible to use a wildcard in the Input Cloud Storage File(s) when creating a job from a template? I seem to be able to read the read the different files through this method but get a Unable to get Table error. Thanks for you response.